# how to compile test examples alsa

Tags: linux, compilation, alsa

I would like to compile the pcm.c file placed in the 'test' directory from alsa-lib.
What I already did was: make pcm resulting in getting besides the pcm.c a pcm.o file.

But I would like to have a executable file.
What is the next thing to do??

Answer (score 2):

```
make check
```

NB: I tested this on [alsa-lib-1.0.27.2](ftp://ftp.alsa-project.org/pub/lib/alsa-lib-1.0.27.2.tar.bz2)

Answer (score 1):

When you run the `make` command, both the object and the executable files are created:

```
$ make pcm
  CC     pcm.o
  CCLD   pcm
```

If the `pcm` target were not created, `make` would output an error message.

Comment: Hi, it created pcm.o, but is it not executable.

Comment: The executable file is not `pcm.o` but the other one.